# Keys event 'AltGr + S' is treated as 'Ctrl + alt + s'

Tags: c#

I have script with Keyboard shortcuts which looks like this:

```
private void MainView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
    {
      backstageViewButtonItem_Save_ItemClick(null, null);
    }
    if (e.Control && e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
    {
      backstageViewButtonItem_SaveAs_ItemClick(null, null);
    }
}
```

The problem:
When I press <kbd>AltRs</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> then my functions for saving are triggered. It looks like <kbd>AltRs</kbd> is treated as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>.

Is there any possibility to recognize that it is only <kbd>alt</kbd> pressed, not <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>, so this functions will not be triggered?

Comment: Yes, use the left alt key.

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  There is no virtual key for AltGr.  Also what a user will have to use when his keyboard does not have an AltGr key.

Comment: I didn't want to use AltGr key, maybe my description was not clear. I wanted to NOT execute my code under 'ctrl+alt+s' event when user press combination AltGr+s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key:

> To allow the specific functionality of AltGr when typing non-English text on such keyboards, Windows allows it to be emulated by pressing the Alt key together with the Control key

...

> Therefore, it is recommended that this combination not be used as a modifier in Windows keyboard shortcuts...

So: Don't do that.

Comment: So I cannot add shotcut 'ctrl+s' and 'ctr+alt+s' in my program, because there is a risk that someone can trigger it by 'AltRs+s'?

Comment: As far as Windows is concerned, AltGr+S is the same keystroke as Ctrl+Alt+S. So you can have Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Alt+S, but you can't tell whether that second one was really Ctrl+Alt+S or AltGr+S.

Comment: Note that you don't need keyboard accelerators for _every_ command in your application, and -- in my opinion -- "Save As" is not commonly used and shouldn't have one. "Save All", on the other hand, _should_ (looking at you, VS Code...).

Comment: A common alternativ is Ctrl+Shift+S (E.g. 'Save all' for VS).